# Installing ceph on a single machine with cephdeploy ubuntu 14.04 64 bit

Tags: software-installation, ceph

I am unable to figure out how to install and deploy ceph on a single machine with ceph deploy. I have ubuntu 14.04 and have installed devstack. I am trying to install ceph on the same machine  and interface with openstack. I have tried the following steps  but it says that mkcephfs does not exist and I read that it is deprecated and ceph - deploy is there. But documentation talks about multiple nodes. I am lost as to how to use ceph deploy and install and setup ceph on a single machine. Pl guide me. I tried the following steps earlier which was given for mkcephfs.

<<( reference http://eu.ceph.com/docs/wip-6919/start/quick-start/ 
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ceph
(2) Execute hostname -s on the command line to retrieve the name of your host. Then, replace {hostname} in the sample configuration file with your host name. Execute ifconfig on the command line to retrieve the IP address of your host. Then, replace {ip-address} with the IP address of your host. Finally, copy the contents of the modified configuration file and save it to /etc/ceph/ceph.conf. This file will configure Ceph to operate a monitor, two OSD daemons and one metadata server on your local machin

[osd]
    osd journal size = 1000
    filestore xattr use omap = true

```
# Execute $ hostname to retrieve the name of your host,
# and replace {hostname} with the name of your host.
# For the monitor, replace {ip-address} with the IP
# address of your host.
```

[mon.a]

```
host = {hostname}
mon addr = {ip-address}:6789
```

[osd.0]
    host = {hostname}

[osd.1]
    host = {hostname}

[mds.a]
    host = {hostname}

sudo mkdir /var/lib/ceph/osd/ceph-0
sudo mkdir /var/lib/ceph/osd/ceph-1
sudo mkdir /var/lib/ceph/mon/ceph-a
sudo mkdir /var/lib/ceph/mds/ceph-a

cd /etc/ceph
sudo mkcephfs -a -c /etc/ceph/ceph.conf -k ceph.keyring

sudo service ceph start
ceph health

> > >

Answer (score 2):

This is a recipe that I use for starting Ceph on a single node using `ceph-deploy`.

```
export DATA_DEV=sdb
export JRNL_DEV=sdc
export HOST=kyoto
ceph-deploy install $HOST
ceph-deploy new $HOST
echo "osd crush chooseleaf type = 0" >> ceph.conf
echo "osd pool default size = 1" >> ceph.conf
ceph-deploy mon create-initial $HOST
ceph-deploy disk zap kyoto:$DATA_DEV
ceph-deploy disk zap kyoto:$JRNL_DEV
ceph-deploy osd create kyoto:$DATA_DEV:$JRNL_DEV
sudo chmod +r /etc/ceph/ceph.client.admin.keyring
```

Comment: Hi,I am getting the following error on trying , can you pl help <<ceph-deploy install $HOST
[ceph_deploy.conf][DEBUG ] found configuration file at: /home/iiit/.cephdeploy.conf
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ] Invoked (1.5.19): /usr/bin/ceph-deploy install kyoto
[ceph_deploy.install][DEBUG ] Installing stable version firefly on cluster ceph hosts kyoto
[ceph_deploy.install][DEBUG ] Detecting platform for host kyoto ...
ssh: Could not resolve hostname kyoto: Name or service not known
[ceph_deploy][ERROR ] RuntimeError: connecting to host: kyoto resulted in errors: HostNotFound kyoto

Comment: you need to customize the script for your host and the names of the storage devices you are using.